# How to get clipboard working for shared VMs on VMWare Workstation

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, remote, clipboard

You can connect to shared VMs running on VMWare Workstation 8 if you [configured your VMWare correctly.](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005585) Host and client are both Windows 7.

One disadvantage of shared VMs is: The clipboard feature gets disabled for security reasons.
I don't care about security in this case. There are no sensitive data.

Is there a workaround  or a trick to re-enable the clipboard for shared VMs?

---

#### What I've tried

I added the following parameters to my VMX file as it's [suggested for VMWare vSphere](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026437).
But it doesn't work for VMWare Workstation. (VMWare tools is installed)

```
isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever discover a fix for this? Just came across this problem myself.

Comment: @KGChristensen No, sadly.

Comment: Does it works to share clipboard between host OS and guest OS, installing __Guest Addition__ (probably setting __bidirectional__ and restarting them)? If needed give a look to [this answer and its references](http://superuser.com/a/932538/257269)

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you installed [VMware Tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018377) on the guest vm?
2. Does other VMware Tools functionality appear to be working?

   - Can you - when your VM is in windowed mode - drag and drop a file from your host onto the problem VM?
   - Can you confirm there are two 'vmwaretoolsd' tasks running in the Windows Task Manager? One for SYSTEM user, one for your current
     user? You may need to click 'show tasks for all users'.
3. Is there any antivirus software running on the guest vm? If so, can
   you disable it and test again?

Comment: missing (not running) `VMware Tools` (`vmtoolsd.exe`) in the user session was the cause of non-working shared clipboard in my case (VMware Workstation 15.5.7). I had to log all users off, then logged in as the user, and... the shared clipboard started working! :)